# Global Variables causing a crash in nodejs index file

Tags: node.js, ejs

So, I am declaring a variable that I should be able to use anywhere:

```
// Global Variables
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Mob Database
  db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs').then(results => {
    req.mobs = results;
    res.locals.mobs = req.mobs;
  });

  next();
});
```

Here is where I'm using it:

```
<select id="monster">
 <% for (var i = 0; i < mobs.length; ++i) { %>
  <option name="mobs" value="<%= mobs[i].id %>"><%= mobs[i].name %></option>
 <% } %>
</select>
```

It works fine for the first load, going back and forth in my views, however once I refresh a couple times it crashes and says "mobs is undefined": Here is the full error log:

```
    74|                 <form name="mobget">
    75|                   <select id="monster">
 >> 76|                   <% for (var i = 0; i < mobs.length; ++i) { %>
    77|                       <option name="mobs" value="<%= mobs[i].id %>"><%= mobs[i].name %></option>
    78|                   <% } %>
    79|                   </select>

mobs is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:62:28)
    at returnedFn (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /home/kogadmin/www/server.js:112:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I just don't understand it. I don't understand how it can work most of the time, then after a few refreshes it all of the sudden just crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the order of execution is not guaranteed, you could be calling next() before the query is complete. Effectively, we're racing code in next() with the db query.

That is why mobs is undefined, the query sometimes has not finished yet.

I'd suggest only calling next once the query is complete. e.g.

```
// Global Variables
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Mob Database
    db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs').then(results => {
        req.mobs = results;
        res.locals.mobs = req.mobs;

        // Now it's safe to call next.
        next();

     }).catch((err) => {
         console.error('Error occurred during query: ', err);
         // Consider sending back a 500 here.
     })
});
```

Comment: I've run into this issue loads of times :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this method of saving and retrieving the data globally. Create a separate map which will be stored in the current session and create a route in which you want to show that data.

**map.js**

```
var hashmapSession = {};

exports.sess = {
  set : function(key, value){
    hashmapSession[key] = value;
  },
  get : function(key){
    return hashmapSession[key];
  },
  delete : function(key){
    delete hashmapSession[key];
  },
  all : function(){
    return hashmapSession;
  }
};
```

Now use your existing code to fetch the data from Database, but instead saving it to `res.locals` use the above map. For example:

```
var hashmap = require('./hashmap');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Mob Database
  db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs').then(results => {
     if(results)
      hashmap.sess.set('global', results);
  });

  next();
});
```

Now create an endpoint to render the saved data. For example:

```
app.get('/showData', function(req, res){
  var data = hashmap.sess.get('global');
  res.render('main', data);
})
```

Note: Here **'main'** is your main.ejs file.

Comment: This is interesting, and may use this if I ever need to declare more than a few variables at a time. But I am curious.... say if I did `var data = { mobs: hashmap.sess.get('mobs'), settings: hashmap.sess.get('settings') }`, after declaring them as necessary, of course. After doing `res.render('main', data);` Could I use it like such: `data.mobs and data.settings`?

Comment: Yes you can use it this way too.

Comment: But using your `locals` variable only in the view like `locals.mobs` and `locals.settings`.